# Smack service discovery without login gives bad-request(400)

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am trying to discover items that a pubsub service provides. When I log into the target server, I can get the response successfully. But when I connect bu do not login, it gives a bad request error.

This is the code:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(serverAddress, 5222);
config.setServiceName(serviceName);
connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login(userName, password); //!!!when I remove this line, bad request error is received

ServiceDiscoveryManager discoManager = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
DiscoverItems items;
try {
items = discoManager.discoverItems("pubsubservice." + serverName);
} catch (XMPPException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a way to discover items when the user is not logged in, but the connection is established?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must authenticate to send stanzas to any JID in XMPP (otherwise they would not be able to reply to you, since they wouldn't know your address).

Perhaps one option for you is anonymous authentication. Most servers support it, and it creates a temporary account on the server for you, with a temporary JID. You don't need a password, and login time is quick.

Answer (score 0):

@MattJ is correct and you could try using anon login.  That will get you part way there.

Your current request will only get you the nodes though, after which you will have to get the items for each node.  It would be simpler to use **[PubsubManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/pubsub/PubSubManager.html)** to get the information you want since it provides convenience methods for accessing/using all things pubsub.

Try the [documentation here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html), the ***getAffiliations()*** method is what you are looking for.

BTW, I believe the typical default service name for pubsub is **pubsub** not **pubsubservice**.  At least this is the case for Openfire.